# Where can I order a Kasket online?

Tags: product-recommendation, clothing

According to Wikipedia a **Kasket** also known as a kashkettel or kasket) is a cap, usually made of felt, worn mainly by Hasidic Jewish children as an alternative to the kippah. It has a crown, a band and peak. From the beginning of the 20th century until the Second World War, many Russian Jews and Polish Jews wore this cap as part of their everyday dress

Comment: https://www.villagehatshop.com/product/greek-fisherman-caps/451139-90194/jaxon-hats-herringbone-wool-blend-fiddlers-cap.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw5rbsBRCFARIsAGEYRwcqpOToydU3s2LWVfNrSMXK7_sxsEblfybjmujtSH2fZW2QVjIN-GYaAmTFEALw_wcB

Comment: The one used by various chassidic groups today looks very different from that. It is basically a hard elongated cylinder (an oval seem from above) in black velvet, completely flat on top. It has a tiny brim at the front. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/kUSEWdG.png)

Comment: I agree it does not look real